# Force hyperlinks on any page I browse to be underlined

Tags: browser, html, hyperlink

There are a few websites I use that have a lot of links, however, they have it set up so the links are not underlined. This is driving me bonkers and me and my coworkers are having a heck of a time using it. Later we find that some innocent looking words are actually links to useful functionality!

Is there such a thing as a browser add-in or setting that will force every link on the page to always be underlined, or at least come close? I don't have access to the pages' code.

I'm using IE 8. But any options, suggestions, or even links to articles describing why links should be underlined are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE, go under Internet Options/ Advanced Tab.  There is an option called Underline hyperlinks Always.  Then turn it on.

Comment: That sounded so hopeful! But it dind't work. I saw this in the CSS file controlling the links: .ms-navitem A:link { COLOR: #006983; FONT-SIZE: 100%; TEXT-DECORATION: none } .ms-navitem A:hover { COLOR: #006983; FONT-SIZE: 100%; TEXT-DECORATION: underline } AND I don't have control over that.